# p-dataview filtering problem using p-galleria, images not lining up correctly

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, primeng

When I'm using the search bar to filter a name in the array, the images in p-galleria don't correctly line up with the card.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/6lrgf1-eppgfm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdata-view-sorting-demo.html

I think problem is i'm directly referencing the array in p-galleria and bypassing p-dataview.

I tried referencing through p-dataview but then i can only get 1 image to show in the thumbnails of p-galleria.

Comment: cannot reproduce your issue in provide stackblitz